# Php. Подправить url

Tags: url, php

```
$nowostnik[$i]['link'] = (string) $item->link;
$test = $nowostnik[$i]['link'];
echo substr($test, 0, strpos($test, 'url=' ));
```

http://news.com/news/url?sa=ghjghjghjg&url=http://www.foxnews.com/us/2014/07/31/trial-set-for-8-greenpeace-activists-in-cincinnati-pg-protest-that-included-zip/

Обрезает все после (**url=**)

*Мне бы хотелось, чтобы обрезало все что **до***, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Пробуй:

```
$nowostnik[$i]['link'] = substr($text,strpos($item->link,'http', 2),strlen($item->link));
```

**Обвновление**

Может так?

```
$test = (string) $item->link;
echo substr($text,strpos($test,'http', 2),strlen($test));
```

Comment: Не подошло, все урл обрезало... Изменил описание задачи, так будет проще понять

Comment: сработало, но выкидывает из рамок <br /><a class="rmorelink" href="'.$test.'">More</a>';

То есть где-то отдельно на странице перед <a href="

Comment: вот этот вариант работает, но урл перед <a href=" показывается

    $test = (string) $item->link; echo substr($text,strpos($test,'http', 2),strlen($test));

Comment: опиши подробно всё, решим завтра

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
$test = explode('url=', $test);
echo $test[0];
```